# Can I refactor current code answers and post it as new answers?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

For example, if a current answer looks like:

```
int count;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
}
```

Can I post a refactored version:

```
for(int i=0,count=0;i<5;i++){
}
```

as new answer? If so, is it plagiarism?

Comment: Try a more realistic example, nobody would (or should) post this as a separate post.  Just keep in mind that deriving your own answer from existing ones is *always* valid and encouraged, just provide attribution.

Comment: Your refactored version doesn't exhibit the same behavior as the original, though.

Comment: The term "refactor" could cover all manor of sins and in general improvements are welcome, but if all you are doing is formatting the same algorithm differently then I wouldn't bother - in the same way that editing the original authors code based on subjective opinion is discouraged, your personal preferences don't add any value to the question as a whole.

Comment: If you just reformat the code you haven't changed much. You would have to give attribution but even then I could argue that your answer doesn't add much (substantial) and rather only clutters the site. Please don't do it if it doesn't give a substantial advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would indeed call this plagiarism. **If someone came up with an idea on how to solve a certain problem and you agree that you would do it the same way**, but you just have a minor syntax improvement/alternative- you shouldn't definitely post this as a separate answer and get the credit for it. I believe that the main purpose of this site is to correctly/efficiently solve programming related problems- not tending code or nicer syntax- though that's also have it's place.

When I encounter such situation, I usually post in comments and see if OP is willing to edit it into his answer. Alternatively, if I strongly feel that my suggestion could benefit future readers, I would edit it into the answer by adding something like "*Alternatively, you could also do:*" or something similar.

Again, as @Hans said, nobody should post minor syntax improvements as their own answer. That's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it deserves to be a new answer since it has an added value, go for it. You can mention the other answerer, give him a credit and explain how your answer differs. Otherwise, if the change is really minor, you should ask OP to change their question by themselves (if they think it's indeed better).

Comment: "You can mention" - You can or you must?

Comment: @Trilarion nothing is a must. If I have a significant improvement on someone's else answer, that has an added value, I do mention him.

Comment: Nothing is a must. That's not true. I thought about the license if you for example take content of someone else and mix and share it you would have to give attribution. So it seems you would rather pretend you came up with the refactored version by yourself. Not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: @Trilarion I wasn't referring everything, just this specific case. Maybe I should've said it better.

Comment: What I think is that someone could refactor existing code just to claim that it's his original work and circumvent the otherwise obligatory attribution. On the other hand if attribution is given and it's only a refactoring the solution is not performing better, it just looks better. The question is then how much value there is in better (or worse) formatting. Do we want three versions of every answer (content-wise) all a bit refactored? How would SO look like if everyone would do what the questioner proposes here?

Comment: I totally agree.